# Are there parallels to Asterisk AMI and Asterisk AGI in FreeSWITCH?

Tags: voip, asterisk, freeswitch

Asterisk has [Asterisk Manager Interface (AMI)](http://www.the-asterisk-book.com/unstable/asterisk-manager-api.html) and [Asterisk Gateway Interface (AGI)](http://www.asterisk.org/docs/asterisk/trunk/applications/agi), using which one can trigger PHP scripts at certain events from Asterisk. Using the same PHP scripts can also instruct Asterisk what to do next to a call/conference. Are there parallels to AMI and AGI in FreeSWITCH?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the AMI you're looking for the [Event Socket Library](http://wiki.freeswitch.org/wiki/Event_Socket_Library).  There are a few examples available on the [mod_event_socket](http://wiki.freeswitch.org/wiki/Mod_event_socket) page.

AGI is a little different.  You can do things similar in FreeSWITCH but they would recommend using [lua](http://wiki.freeswitch.org/wiki/Mod_lua).  I've personally used the FreeSWITCH [mod_perl](http://wiki.freeswitch.org/wiki/Mod_perl) with good results.

Comment: thank you for your help in this question. I have added the link to lua in your reply. On a different note, can you please look at this question: http://serverfault.com/q/345784/105376   I would greatly appreciate your response.